# Why is React router not unmounting previous content when route is changed?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to build a React app which fetches news from the news API and displays it based on the category. It uses Infinite scrolling and displays 6 news items at a time.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<>
      <BrowserRouter>

        <Navbar />
        <Routes>

          <Route exact path="/general" key="general" element={<News category={'general'} />} />
          <Route exact path="/sports" key="sports" element={<News category={'sports'} />} />
          <Route exact path="/entertainment" key="entertainment" element={<News category={'entertainment'} />} />
          <Route exact path="/health" key="health" element={<News category={'health'} />} />
          <Route exact path="/science" key="science" element={<News category={'science'} />} />
          <Route exact path="/" key="everything" element={<News/>} />

        </Routes>

      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
    )
  }
}
```

here is the code of **News** component

```
export default class News extends Component {

  static defaultProps = {
    pageLimit: 6,
    category:'',
    country: 'in'
  }

  static propTypes = {
    pageLimit: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    country: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      articles: [],
      loading: true,
      page: 1,
      totalResults: 1,
      pageSize: 1
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&apiKey=445f58e1d17c4229b23e3965d19197c7&category=${this.props.category}&page=1&pagesize=${this.props.pageLimit}`;
    let res = await fetch(url);
    let data = await res.json();
    this.setState({
      loading: false,
      totalResults: data.totalResults,
      articles: data.articles,
      pageSize: Math.ceil(data.totalResults / this.props.pageLimit)
    });
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&apiKey=445f58e1d17c4229b23e3965d19197c7&category=${this.props.category}&page=${this.state.page + 1}&pagesize=${this.props.pageLimit}`;
    
    this.setState({
      loading: true,
      page: this.state.page + 1,
    })

    let res = await fetch(url);
    let data = await res.json();
    this.setState({
      loading: false,
      articles: this.state.articles.concat(data.articles),
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (<>

      <InfiniteScroll
        dataLength={this.state.articles.length}
        next={this.fetchData}
        hasMore={this.state.articles.length !== this.state.totalResults}
        loader={<Spinner />}
      >
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='row'>
            {
              this.state.articles.map((elem) => {
                return <div className='col-md-4' key={elem.url}>
                  <Newscomp title={elem.title ? elem.title.slice(0, 30) : ""} url={elem.url} imgUrl={elem.urlToImage} description={elem.content ? elem.content.slice(0, 40) : ""} />
                </div>
              })
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </InfiniteScroll>
    </>
    )
  }
}
```

when I try to change the category lets say from **general** to **sports** the previous 6 news items from general remain but on scrolling down I get the news from sports category.

I want it to completely remove the previous content and show the newly fetched content when I switch categories. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an optimization when 2 or more routes render the same routed component. In this case, the `News` component. The `News` component will remain mounted and only the `category` prop is changing, so the `News` component can respond to *that* change. You have a couple options:

1. Move the `key` to the correct component. It is rather irrelevant on the `Route` component. Move the `key` prop to the routed component to "force remount" it.

   ```
   <BrowserRouter>
     <Navbar />
     <Routes>
       <Route path="/general" element={<News key="general" category={'general'} />} />
       <Route path="/sports" element={<News key="sports" category={'sports'} />} />
       <Route
         path="/entertainment"
         element={<News key="entertainment" category={'entertainment'} />}
       />
       <Route path="/health" element={<News key="health" category={'health'} />} />
       <Route path="/science" element={<News key="science" category={'science'} />} />
       <Route path="/" element={<News key="everything" />} />
     </Routes>
   </BrowserRouter>
   ```
2. Implement the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method to handle responding to the `category` prop updating.

   ```
   export default class News extends Component {
     ...

     fetchInitialData = async () => {
       const { category, country, pageLimit } = this.props;
       this.setState({ loading: true }); // set loading state

       const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${country}&apiKey=445f58e1d17c4229b23e3965d19197c7&category=${category}&page=1&pagesize=${pageLimit}`;

       try {
         const res = await fetch(url);
         const data = await res.json();

         this.setState({
           totalResults: data.totalResults,
           articles: data.articles,
           pageSize: Math.ceil(data.totalResults / pageLimit)
         });
       } catch(error) {
         // handle any rejected Promises or thrown errors
       } finally {
         this.setState({ loading: false }); // clear loading state
       }
     }

     componentDidMount() {
       fetchInitialData();
     }

     componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
       if (prevProps.category !== this.props.category) {
         fetchInitialData();
       }
     }

     ...
   }
   ```